# How to make multiple group in 1 row in SQL Server Reporting Services - SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2014

I have created a report to show some data, but I need to get the sum for each group field value. But so far, I can only make a total for one field. From the sample table below, I can only make sums based on UOM or base UOM. I can't do it for both. List of UOM and Base UOM may vary depends on data. Is it possible to make it like the result below?

| Stock Date | Product Code | Product Name | Qty | UOM | Base Qty | Base UOM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12-May-23 | P002142213 | Product A | 150 | PC | 150 | PC |
| 15-May-23 | P032142432 | Product B | 200 | PC | 200 | PC |
| 18-May-23 | P947289323 | Product C | 160 | CB | 80 | BAL |
| 21-May-23 | P012412323 | Product D | 250 | CB | 250 | CB |
| 24-May-23 | P123412332 | Product E | 100 | PC | 100 | PC |
| 27-May-23 | P124213232 | Product F | 260 | CB | 260 | CB |
|  |  | **Total** | **570** | **CB** | **80** | **BAL** |
|  |  |  | **450** | **PC** | **510** | **CB** |
|  |  |  |  |  | **450** | **PC** |

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Why have you tagged 2 different versions of SSRS, one of which has been *completely* unsupported for over **4 years**?

Comment: @ThomA, i just update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer uses tables within merged cells to achieve a result that is very close to your requirements.

I started by reproducing your data then added a simple table showing the data.

I then added a few rows outside the current details group so the rows always appear below the main data.

The first new row is just so we can control the gap between the detail and summary data.

On the second new row I then merged the `Qty` and `UOM` columns and made the row height bigger (double normal height).

I then inserted a table into this merged cell. Inside thsi table I set the row grouping and sort both to the `UOM` field and `=SUM(Fields!Qty.Value)` as the value expression.

I then repeated this process for the Base qty and Base UOM columns.

I then cleaned up the formatting by removing borders from the new rows.

The final result looks like this...

[image]

Here's a short GIF to show the process. (Right-click and open in new window to watch it maximised).

**NOTE**: *I didn't realise the crucial part was chopped off the bottom of the recording. When I right-click the merged cell I do "Insert ==> Table"*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have a small finite number of UOM and Base UOM values then you can add rows to the bottom of you table (make sure they are outside your existing row groups).

Then you'll have to hardcode the label (e.g. "CB") and the qty expression for each textbox.

For example for total CB Qty you'll need

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!UOM.Value = "CB", Fields!Qty.Value, 0))
```

repeat this for each instance.

Comment: list of UOM and Base UOM may vary and flexible depends on list of data, i can't hardcode the label of UOM / Base UOM

Comment: you will probably have to create two more tables to summarise your data then. I don't think you'll be able to do exactly what you want.

Comment: I was thinking like this to create two tables, one for display list of data and one more to show summarise of my data.

Comment: Actually there is a way to do this. I'll post an new answer shortly.